# Access the groups and it's users in Active directory using java code

Tags: active-directory

I am trying to write a java program to list the groups and users of that group but I am not able to do that. please I am getting the error..

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - No Such Object]; Remaining name: 'ou=cag.cdroot.net'
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3042)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2963)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2770)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.searchAux(LdapCtx.java:1824)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_search(LdapCtx.java:1747)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_search(ComponentDirContext.java:380)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.search(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:350)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.search(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:333)
    at javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.search(Unknown Source)
    at GetList.main(GetList.java:53)
```

Please if anyone know this help me out. It is very important for me.....
thanks........

Comment: I feel your pain.  Google search lead me here.  No joy (yet)